# Bypassing Cancan Role Validation in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a helper which checks a current_user's role to protect some attributes from being edited by an unauthorised user.

The validation works fine apart from when I'm in the console. Obviously there's no user but it's still trying to validate and I get:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `has_role?' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I bypass this validation or is there a better way to achieve what I'm doing?

Location Model:

```
  validate :check_archived_status, :on => :update

  def check_archived_status
    unless UserHelper.staff
      if self.archived == false
        if stuff == otherstuff
          do some other stuff
        end
      end
    end    
  end
```

UserHelper:

```
def self.staff
  staff = User.current_user.has_role?('Super', 'Admin', 'Tech')
end
```

Comment: Can't you populate `current_user` with some random user on your console? `current_user = User.last`, so the validation doesn't give you any errors.

Comment: I've been faffing for a solution for days and that's the easiest solution in the world! Can you shove it in an answer so I can accept it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you populate `current_user` with some random user on your console?
Like this: `current_user = User.last`, so the validation doesn't give you any errors.